# Making a message disappear. React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using firebase to make an authentication system in react native and I want to print for user a text input error like 'email invalid' and i succeeded but not it just sits there. How can i make i disappear after a while? Like put a timer on it or something

Here is the function:

```
handleSignUp = () => {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .catch(error => this.setState({errorMessage: error.message}))
  }
```

and here is the section where i use it:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
   style={styles.userBtn}
   onPress={this.handleSignUp}>
   <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>SignUp</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KecCF.png)
And that underlined text is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) life cycle which will be called right after component updated

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({errorMessage:''}), 3000);
  }
```

Comment: and where should i use it?

Comment: componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. I've attached a link with full explanation.

Comment: i'm getting this error: 'text strings must rendered within a <Text> component'

Comment: @Nicoara you should use:  this.state.errorMessage &&
        <Text>
          Error message: {this.state. errorMessage}
        </Text>
      }

Comment: got rid of the error but the errorMessage is still there

Comment: It is hard to debug your code without seeing it, but setTimeout should work :) you can start with a simple exmple: setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

Comment: @Nicoara feel free to mark this answer as correct, so other developers will learn from it too :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a `setTimeout` right after setting the error message, like this:

```
handleSignUp = () => {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({errorMessage: error.message});
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId); // Prevents remove error if many errors occur in less than 3000ms
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => this.setState({errorMessage: ''}), 3000);
    })
}
```

And don't forget to clear the timeout in order to prevent leaks:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
}
```